# What classes/methods to hook up to do an action after customer's profile is updated?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, di

I intend to make a call to an API endpoint after a customer's profile information, such as name, date of birth, etc, are updated. The update can be done either by the admin through the admin panel or by the user himself through his account on the frontend.

I'm very new to Magento2. I read up on Magento2 modules and if I understood correctly, it seems like I could do this by hooking up my method with the relevant core classes in the di.xml and create my own `after*()` method. If this is the case, which are the classes and methods should I be hooking up with to do something after a customer's profile information is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following class is responsible for update customer information from frontend my account
[Go to class](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/EditPost.php)

Check **execute()** method.

[This line is responsible for save/update customer information](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/EditPost.php#L154)

Comment: Thanks! The description of the `execute()` method says that "Change customer email or password action". Is this method responsible for customer changing email address, name, date of birth, gender, etc?

Comment: Yes, url : your_url/customer/account/edit

Comment: I will try out your suggestion. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It seems like this only works when user updates his profile from the frontend. It doesn't work when I update the customer's account information from the admin panel.

Comment: yes, you are right. For admin got to -> https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Save.php#L176